# How to write this algorithm more efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an assignment where I have to write an algorithm which 'splits' the array in two. Left side should be odd numbers, and right side should be even numbers. Both sides should be sorted in ascending order. I'm not allowed to use temp arrays or existing api.

I have managed to make a working method, problem is with an array of say 100 000 integers, it takes approximately 15 seconds to finish. The requirement is 0,1 seconds, so I obviously have a lot to improve. I'm not looking for someone to spoon-feed me the answer, just a nudge in the right direction. Please don't write any working code for me, though I would like to know if and why something I've written is bad!

What I have so far:

```
public static void delsortering(int[] a){           

        int oddnum = 0;
        int n = a.length;

        for(int k : a){ //finds how many odd numbers there are
            if((k & 1) != 0) oddnum++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
            if((a[i] & 1) != 0){ //finds odd numbers
                for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    if((a[j] & 1) == 0) //looks for even numbers to change pos with
                        switch(a, j, i);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
            int from = i < oddnum ? 0 : oddnum;
            int to = i < oddnum ? oddnum - i: n - i + oddetall;
            int m   = maxValue(a, from, to); //finds max value in specified range
            switch(a, m, to - 1); //puts said max value at specified index
        }
    }
```

Appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: For the first part, splitting into odds/evens: Nested for loops get you n^2 . You need to have 2 indexes, walk one from left, one from right. When the index sees the wrong number, it stops and lets the other index walk. When both see wrong numbers, swap. Done when they meet.

Comment: You could first sort the array - O(nlogn), which will then just need to split away in order with another O(n).

Comment: This is not a question for  Code Review since the op clearly asks for an algorithm and not improvement on his existing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be:

- Firstly keep two variables that point to the first and last elements of the array e.g `x=0; y=N-1`.
- Then start moving `x` to the right until you find  an even number (all numbers until now **are odd** !!!), then start moving `y` to the left until you find an odd number (all number you examine while decreasing-moving left  `y` **are even** until the first one odd you find !!!)
- **Swap values x,y ,increase x,y and repeat the same procedure until x,y get crossed**.

Then you have the array with evens on the right and odd on the left but not ordered. So you could count during the above procedure the number of odds and evens in order to know where there are separated in the array let's say in `k` index.

- `Sort array[0 - k], Sort array[k+1 - N]`.

***Complexity:***  `O(n)` for the first part (x,y are only once moving to one direction) and `O(nlogn)` for both sorts so `O(nlogn)` which is better than `O(n^2)` that is your solution.